# Add link to text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

Trying myself at extending some corporate CRM website I'm trying to write a Chrome extension to ease my daily work.

Trying to move a link from a td to another td in a table for every tr.

```
$('tbody.sort tr').each(function() {


     var addcall = $(this).children('td')[45];
     var link = addcall.innerHTML;
     console.log(link);

     var agent = $(this).children('td')[13];
     console.log(agent);

     $('agent').html(link);


});
```

I do get my correct HTML link which outputs:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Clist_act('assign', '', 'trading_rooms_clients', 'user_ID', 75727,this,event);" class="Action jq-assign">Add Call</a>
```

I want to add this using `html()`, `wrap()` or `attr(href,...)` to agent which is:

```
<td class="jq-td-sale-person" id="Clist_row_75727_sales_person_ID_12" style="text-align:left;">Michael</td>
```

Ideally I'd like to keep Michael and add the link but if the link says Add Call it's fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append the link to child td:13.

```
$('tbody.sort tr').each(function() {
     var addcall = $(this).children('td')[45];
     var link = addcall.innerHTML;
     console.log(link);

     var agent = $(this).children('td')[13];
     console.log(agent);

     $(agent).append(" " + link);
});
```

So change your line

```
$('agent').html(link);
```

with this one:

```
$(agent).append(" " + link);
```

or you can write all your code as follow:

```
$('tr td:nth-child(14)').append(" " + $('tr td:nth-child(46)').html());
```

Comment: wow so simple yet so complicated when you don't know the syntax. Thanks so much I now learnt how to address it correctly. thank you !

Comment: Yes.. It is "beautiful of simple"!

Comment: ok that last line just twisted my brain so hard my nose is bleeding :) very nice. Thanks again Mara.